# C Converting Character Array to Integers

Tags: c, char, int, ascii

I have seen many posts on this but they are not quite what I need.

I have a char array which contains `[8,2,A,8]` but is encoded as `[0x38, 0x32, 0x61, 0x38]`. These are the ASCII representations of `82A8`. I need to put these values into a `uint64_t`. What I am currently doing is stepping through the array, adding the value to the variable then shifting the variable right by 4.

```
for(i=start; i<end; i++)
{
    value |= testArray[i] - '0'
    value = value << 4;
}
```

The issue comes in at the character `A` when I shift this in it shows up as `1` rather than `A`. I need a simple way I can loop through this array and take the ascii encoded values and convert them to an integer.

82A8 should equal 33448 but I can not get this to calculate properly.

Comment: What is the expected `uint64_t` value?

Comment: Ok, `strtoull`. If you don't mind terminating your char array with `\0`.

Comment: The expected value for 0x82A8 is 33448 deciaml

Comment: So your array contains `0x38, 0x32, 0x61, 0x38`, period.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that is correct, those are the ascii values for 82A8

Comment: ... and you want to convert from the hexadecimal representation "82A8" to the number 33448, correct?

Comment: @MichaelWalz that is correct

Comment: OK, so the question title is misleading. Anyway, the answer below is correct.

Comment: The answer below still gives the wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is:

```
char digits[]={'8','2','A','8'};
int value= 0;

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    if (digits[i]>='A')
         value = value*16 + digits[i] - 'A' + 10;
    else
         value = value*16 + digits[i] - '0';
}
```

Comment: This answer gives me a value of 33800 for my input array

Comment: @MichaelMiner there was a small error in the answer (missing `+ 10`). It's corrected by now.